# ESLint imports/modules are treated as undefined

Tags: javascript, polymer, eslint

I'm using Webpack with Polymer, importing a component like so:

```
import '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.html';

class AppShell extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'app-shell'; }
}
```

I left out the rest of the component here. The import is working as expected in my app, but when I am running ESLint, I get the following error message:

```
50:27  error  'Polymer' is not defined  no-undef
```

This is my `package.json`, where I'm defining my ESLint settings. Anyone have an idea why ESLint is not picking up the import properly?

```
{
  "name": "client-meeting-tracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node utils/webserver.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .html,.js */**",
    "build": "node utils/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@startup-boilerplate/inkling": "*",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^3.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "polymer-cli": "^0.17.0",
    "wc-loader": "*",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "commonjs": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
      "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab",
        {
          "SwitchCase": 1
        }
      ],
      "quotes": [
        "error",
        "single"
      ],
      "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
      ]
    },
    "plugins": [
      "html"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Polymer` is defined as a global, so I would [configure `Polymer` as a global](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) in your `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "globals": {
    "Polymer": true
  }
}
```